# How to perform own action on F5 key press in UI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, keyevent

I don't know how to replace the <kbd>F5</kbd> key action in SAPUI5.

I have a button "Refresh" which is reloading my business data in the UI and made some kind of manipulation before showing it on the view. I want to catch the <kbd>F5</kbd>-press so that my method to refresh can be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event listener to the window and call `preventDefault()` to stop it from doing the default thing of reloading.

(After running, click inside the white section to see it working. Otherwise the page will reload)

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key == "F5") event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Since UI5 1.70 ([commit:`59b83bf`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/59b83bf53edf1b80ac7bdbf4b80030817f687806)), applications can define app-wide shortcuts in `manifest.json` and declare the corresponding event handlers in the view.

Here is a **sample: [https://embed.plnkr.co/NKOfisfY7w0MOiX8](https://embed.plnkr.co/NKOfisfY7w0MOiX8?show=manifest.json,view%2FApp.view.xml,controller%2FApp.controller.js,preview&autoCloseSidebar)**

In `manifest.json`:

```json
"sap.ui5": {
  "commands": {
    "MyRefresh": {
      "shortcut": "F5"
    }
```

In the view:

```xml
<AnyUI5Control>
  <dependents>
    <core:CommandExecution xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      command="MyRefresh"
      execute=".onRefreshData"
    />
  </dependents>
</AnyUI5Control>
```

When the control has the focus, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will trigger the event handler `onRefreshData` in the controller.

---

⚠️ Please note that the custom shortcut feature in UI5:

- Is supported **since UI5 1.70**.
- Currently works **only if the control has the focus**. See the [related discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2788).
- Make sure your `shortcut` key combination doesn't overlap with the **existing shortcuts** that the target control already provides.

  - [Existing shortcuts categorized by UI5 controls](https://help.sap.com/products/SAPUI5/bc5a64aac808463baa95b4230f221716/144d377d68784689a9b21565dfa14065.html)
  - [Existing shortcuts provided by SAP Fiori elements](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/0cd318c83ec5473d9a091c1782d03c21)

Comment: Hi Boghyon the problem that i have is that i have to always set the focus so that the trigger can react. i try it  but in the process of time it will be a complaining of the user.

Comment: @LionelSamstag. Do you happen to have a GitHub account? Could you add a  to https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2788 so that UI5 maintainers prioritize the issue?